# Custom layout - Jetpack compose - Cloud layout design like Apple store app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist, android-jetpack-compose-list

Hi i am struggling to build a custom layout for a list of images which is placed and sized like in cloud. [image: Please ser the image] .

The first element in the list have to be placed in the center and the other set elements is placed around the first item. Rest of the elements are placed and sized randomly around it. It should scroll horizontally like a list. Is there any design library for this.
How can i make this using jetpack compose?